# Android buildTypes vs. productFlavors error

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

Decided to switch to from Android gradle plugin 3.5.x to gradle plugin 4.10 with Gradle 6.5 and stuck with mistake.

Here's my build.gradle

```
defaultConfig {

    applicationId "com.example.myapp
    targetSdkVersion targetSdkVersionVar
    multiDexEnabled true
}

flavorDimensions "version"

productFlavors {
    kitkat {
        sourceSets { "src/android/kitkat" }
        dimension "version"
        minSdkVersion minSdkKitkat
        targetSdkVersion targetSdkKitkat
        versionNameSuffix "-kitkat"
    }
    nougat {
        sourceSets { "src/android/nougat" }
        dimension "version"
        minSdkVersion minSdkNougat
        targetSdkVersion targetSdkVersionVar
        versionNameSuffix "-nougat"
    }
}


buildTypes {

    debug {
        multiDexKeepFile file('multidex-config.txt')
        multiDexKeepProguard file('multidex-config.pro')
        minifyEnabled false
        zipAlignEnabled true
        sourceSets {

            //main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
            main {
                java.srcDirs = ['src/android/default/java/', 'src/common/java/']
                jni.srcDirs = [] //disable ndk support
                manifest.srcFile 'src/android/default/AndroidManifest.xml'
                resources.srcDirs = ['src/android/default']
                aidl.srcDirs = ['src/android/default']
                renderscript.srcDirs = ['src/android/default']
                res.srcDirs = ['src/android/default/res']
                assets.srcDirs = ['src/android/default/assets']
            }
            test {
                java.srcDirs = ['src/test/java']
            }
            androidTest {
                java.srcDirs = ['src/androidTest/java']
            }
        }
    }
    release {
        multiDexKeepFile file('multidex-config.txt')
        multiDexKeepProguard file('multidex-config.pro')
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        zipAlignEnabled true
        sourceSets {

            main {
                java.srcDirs = ['src/android/default/java/', 'src/common/java/']
                jni.srcDirs = [] //disable ndk support
                manifest.srcFile 'src/android/default/AndroidManifest.xml'
                resources.srcDirs = ['src/android/default']
                aidl.srcDirs = ['src/android/default']
                renderscript.srcDirs = ['src/android/default']
                res.srcDirs = ['src/android/default/res']
                assets.srcDirs = ['src/android/default/assets']
            }
            test {
                java.srcDirs = ['src/test/java']
            }
            androidTest {
                java.srcDirs = ['src/androidTest/java']
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Trying to build I receive following error messages:

```
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:checkKitkatReleaseLibraries'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:kitkatReleaseReverseMetadataValues'.
   > Could not resolve project :app.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > The consumer was configured to find a usage of 'android-reverse-meta-data' of a component, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'release', attribute 'version' with value 'kitkat'. However we cannot choose between the following variants of project :app:
          - kitkatDebugAndroidTestCompile
          - kitkatDebugAndroidTestRuntime
          - kitkatDebugRuntime
          - kitkatDebugUnitTestCompile
          - kitkatDebugUnitTestRuntime
          - kitkatReleaseRuntime
          - kitkatReleaseUnitTestCompile
          - kitkatReleaseUnitTestRuntime
          - nougatDebugAndroidTestCompile
          - nougatDebugAndroidTestRuntime
          - nougatDebugRuntime
          - nougatDebugUnitTestCompile
          - nougatDebugUnitTestRuntime
          - nougatReleaseRuntime
          - nougatReleaseUnitTestCompile
          - nougatReleaseUnitTestRuntime
        All of them match the consumer attributes:
          - Variant 'kitkatDebugAndroidTestCompile' capability myapp:app:unspecified:
              - Unmatched attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr (required 'release')
                  - Doesn't say anything about its usage (required a usage of 'android-reverse-meta-data')
                  - Provides attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.localToProject' with value 'local to :app' but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Provides attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'androidJvm' but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Doesn't say anything about version (required 'kitkat')
          - Variant 'kitkatDebugAndroidTestRuntime' capability myapp:app:unspecified:
              - Unmatched attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr (required 'release')
                  - Doesn't say anything about its usage (required a usage of 'android-reverse-meta-data')
                  - Provides attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.localToProject' with value 'local to :app' but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Provides attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'androidJvm' but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Doesn't say anything about version (required 'kitkat')
          - Variant 'kitkatDebugRuntime' capability myapp:app:unspecified:
              - Unmatched attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr (required 'release')
                  - Doesn't say anything about its usage (required a usage of 'android-reverse-meta-data')
                  - Provides attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.localToProject' with value 'local to :app' but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Provides attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'androidJvm' but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Doesn't say anything about version (required 'kitkat')
          - Variant 'kitkatDebugUnitTestCompile' capability myapp:app:unspecified:
              - Unmatched attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr (required 'release')
                  - Doesn't say anything about its usage (required a usage of 'android-reverse-meta-data')
                  - Provides attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.localToProject' with value 'local to :app' but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Provides attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'androidJvm' but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Doesn't say anything about version (required 'kitkat')
          - Variant 'kitkatDebugUnitTestRuntime' capability myapp:app:unspecified:
              - Unmatched attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr (required 'release')
                  - Doesn't say anything about its usage (required a usage of 'android-reverse-meta-data')
                  - Provides attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.localToProject' with value 'local to :app' but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Provides attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'androidJvm' but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Doesn't say anything about version (required 'kitkat')
          - Variant 'kitkatReleaseRuntime' capability myapp:app:unspecified:
              - Unmatched attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr (required 'release')
                  - Doesn't say anything about its usage (required a usage of 'android-reverse-meta-data')
                  - Provides attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.localToProject' with value 'local to :app' but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Provides attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'androidJvm' but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Doesn't say anything about version (required 'kitkat')
          - Variant 'kitkatReleaseUnitTestCompile' capability myapp:app:unspecified:
              - Unmatched attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr (required 'release')
                  - Doesn't say anything about its usage (required a usage of 'android-reverse-meta-data')
                  - Provides attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.localToProject' with value 'local to :app' but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Provides attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'androidJvm' but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Doesn't say anything about version (required 'kitkat')
          - Variant 'kitkatReleaseUnitTestRuntime' capability myapp:app:unspecified:
              - Unmatched attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr (required 'release')
                  - Doesn't say anything about its usage (required a usage of 'android-reverse-meta-data')
                  - Provides attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.localToProject' with value 'local to :app' but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Provides attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'androidJvm' but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Doesn't say anything about version (required 'kitkat')
          - Variant 'nougatDebugAndroidTestCompile' capability myapp:app:unspecified:
              - Unmatched attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr (required 'release')
                  - Doesn't say anything about its usage (required a usage of 'android-reverse-meta-data')
                  - Provides attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.localToProject' with value 'local to :app' but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Provides attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'androidJvm' but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Doesn't say anything about version (required 'kitkat')
          - Variant 'nougatDebugAndroidTestRuntime' capability myapp:app:unspecified:
              - Unmatched attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr (required 'release')
                  - Doesn't say anything about its usage (required a usage of 'android-reverse-meta-data')
                  - Provides attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.localToProject' with value 'local to :app' but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Provides attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'androidJvm' but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Doesn't say anything about version (required 'kitkat')
          - Variant 'nougatDebugRuntime' capability myapp:app:unspecified:
              - Unmatched attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr (required 'release')
                  - Doesn't say anything about its usage (required a usage of 'android-reverse-meta-data')
                  - Provides attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.localToProject' with value 'local to :app' but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Provides attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'androidJvm' but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Doesn't say anything about version (required 'kitkat')
          - Variant 'nougatDebugUnitTestCompile' capability myapp:app:unspecified:
              - Unmatched attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr (required 'release')
                  - Doesn't say anything about its usage (required a usage of 'android-reverse-meta-data')
                  - Provides attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.localToProject' with value 'local to :app' but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Provides attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'androidJvm' but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Doesn't say anything about version (required 'kitkat')
          - Variant 'nougatDebugUnitTestRuntime' capability myapp:app:unspecified:
              - Unmatched attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr (required 'release')
                  - Doesn't say anything about its usage (required a usage of 'android-reverse-meta-data')
                  - Provides attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.localToProject' with value 'local to :app' but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Provides attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'androidJvm' but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Doesn't say anything about version (required 'kitkat')
          - Variant 'nougatReleaseRuntime' capability myapp:app:unspecified:
              - Unmatched attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr (required 'release')
                  - Doesn't say anything about its usage (required a usage of 'android-reverse-meta-data')
                  - Provides attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.localToProject' with value 'local to :app' but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Provides attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'androidJvm' but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Doesn't say anything about version (required 'kitkat')
          - Variant 'nougatReleaseUnitTestCompile' capability myapp:app:unspecified:
              - Unmatched attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr (required 'release')
                  - Doesn't say anything about its usage (required a usage of 'android-reverse-meta-data')
                  - Provides attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.localToProject' with value 'local to :app' but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Provides attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'androidJvm' but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Doesn't say anything about version (required 'kitkat')
          - Variant 'nougatReleaseUnitTestRuntime' capability myapp:app:unspecified:
              - Unmatched attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr (required 'release')
                  - Doesn't say anything about its usage (required a usage of 'android-reverse-meta-data')
                  - Provides attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.localToProject' with value 'local to :app' but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Provides attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'androidJvm' but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Doesn't say anything about version (required 'kitkat')
        The following variants were also considered but didn't match the requested attributes:
          - Variant 'kitkatDebugApiElements' capability myapp:app:unspecified declares a component, as well as attribute 'version' with value 'kitkat':
              - Incompatible because this component declares an API of a component, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'debug' and the consumer needed a usage of 'android-reverse-meta-data' of a component, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'release'
          - Variant 'kitkatDebugRuntimeElements' capability myapp:app:unspecified declares a component, as well as attribute 'version' with value 'kitkat':
              - Incompatible because this component declares a runtime of a component, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'debug' and the consumer needed a usage of 'android-reverse-meta-data' of a component, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'release'
          - Variant 'kitkatReleaseApiElements' capability myapp:app:unspecified declares a component, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'release', attribute 'version' with value 'kitkat':
              - Incompatible because this component declares an API of a component and the consumer needed a usage of 'android-reverse-meta-data' of a component
          - Variant 'kitkatReleaseRuntimeElements' capability myapp:app:unspecified declares a component, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'release', attribute 'version' with value 'kitkat':
              - Incompatible because this component declares a runtime of a component and the consumer needed a usage of 'android-reverse-meta-data' of a component
          - Variant 'nougatDebugApiElements' capability myapp:app:unspecified:
              - Incompatible because this component declares an API of a component, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'debug', attribute 'version' with value 'nougat' and the consumer needed a usage of 'android-reverse-meta-data' of a component, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'release', attribute 'version' with value 'kitkat'
          - Variant 'nougatDebugRuntimeElements' capability myapp:app:unspecified:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a runtime of a component, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'debug', attribute 'version' with value 'nougat' and the consumer needed a usage of 'android-reverse-meta-data' of a component, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'release', attribute 'version' with value 'kitkat'
          - Variant 'nougatReleaseApiElements' capability myapp:app:unspecified declares a component, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'release':
              - Incompatible because this component declares an API of a component, as well as attribute 'version' with value 'nougat' and the consumer needed a usage of 'android-reverse-meta-data' of a component, as well as attribute 'version' with value 'kitkat'
          - Variant 'nougatReleaseRuntimeElements' capability myapp:app:unspecified declares a component, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'release':
              - Incompatible because this component declares a runtime of a component, as well as attribute 'version' with value 'nougat' and the consumer needed a usage of 'android-reverse-meta-data' of a component, as well as attribute 'version' with value 'kitkat'
```

Before that, when I was using gradle-tools v 3.x - it was working really fine.

Any thoughts, ideas, hints, clues?

Comment: Experiencing the same issue with not being able to use a library dependency that has different variants than the consumer library. It would be great if anyone has a work around or fix please?

Comment: Where does the `:app:checkKitkatReleaseLibraries` task come from? It’s not clear (to me at least) from your partial build config. A [mcve] would be great …

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following to @Chriki's comment tried to formulate minimal reproducible question and suddenly found a solution. Magic was in statement:

```
android {
    ...
    dynamicFeatures = [":app"]
}
```

Whenever I have commented this line, everything works.

P.S. Here are should be *hateness radiation* to gradle logs/debug messages, actually absense of those logging/messaging. In the end I spent nearly a week trying to find a solution and in the end found by accident.

If @Chriki would post answer I will reward bounty to him.

Answer (score 12):

This error happens in the following case. You have these modules and dependencies:

```
                  app (free/paid)
                   |
featureA       featureB          featureC
   |               |                |
       \                      /
             libraryX (free/paid)
```

`app` module has 2 flavors: `free`, `paid`. None of `feature` modules have those 2 flavors but `libraryX` has it! Now when `feature` modules depend on `libraryX`, they must explicitly tell gradle if they want `freeLibraryXDebug` or `paidLibraryXDebug`. But `feature` modules can't say `freeImplementation(project(":libraryX"))` or `paidImplementation(project(":libraryX"))` because they don't have those flavors themselves.

There are [two ways](https://kiranrao.in/blog/2020/03/31/gradle-missing-flavors/) to solve these:

1. `feature` modules always choose one specific flavor, using `missingDimensionStrategy` in `defaultConfig` as described [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants#resolve_matching_errors). Problem with this approach is `feature` modules always depend on one specific flavor (free/paid) no matter what `app` module flavor is selected (from AndroidStudio "Build Variants" tab on left or from terminal command)
2. `feature` modules also declare 2 flavors (`free`, `paid`), then use `implementation(project(":libraryX"))`. Selected flavor for `app` module will cascade down to `feature` modules and also to `libraryX` module, everything automatically. Problem with this is boilerplate, if you have tens of `feature` modules, they all need to declare 2 flavors in gradle file. To eliminate bilerplate and code duplication, you can extract `productFlavors` declaration to separate gradle file and apply it as `plugin` in every `feature` module. [Example](https://github.com/android10/Android-CleanArchitecture-Kotlin/tree/main/buildSrc) [codes](https://github.com/android10/Android-CleanArchitecture-Kotlin/blob/main/buildSrc/src/main/kotlin/scripts/variants.gradle.kts) for [gradle](https://github.com/android10/Android-CleanArchitecture-Kotlin/blob/c26da374ddaa82ad5a02668e14d11571482d401c/app/build.gradle.kts#L10) kotlin dsl and discussion [here](https://github.com/gradle/kotlin-dsl-samples/issues/1287).

I couldn't find a way to choose `libraryX's` flavor by looking at `app` module's selected flavor, without introducing flavors to `feature` modules in the middle.

Answer (score 9):

It seems that issue you have is that your main project uses your library that has flavor dimensions, and your app doesn't know which one to use. You should Use **missingDimensionStrategy** in the **defaultConfig** block to specify the default flavor. For example :

```
missingDimensionStrategy 'dimension', 'flavor1', 'flavor2'
```

Please check [this](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#resolve_matching_errors) link for more details.

Answer (score -2):

I had the same issue but i'm working with multi gradle files project , after adding the variant on each one it worked fine.

Comment: could you please tell how to add variant. Why its used? Where I have to use?